# What the difference between Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf and Array.isPrototypeOf?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering what is the difference between `Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf` and `Array.isPrototypeOf` I thought it should work the same because I thought it will refer to the same method `isPrototypeOf` but It's look like I was mistaken. Can anybody explain to me why this work like that ?

```js
const exampleArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(exampleArray));
console.log(Array.isPrototypeOf(exampleArray)); // Why this statement returns false ?
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those are both references to
[`Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf), which checks to see if the object it's called on is in the prototype chain of the passed argument.

For the `exampleArray`, the prototype chain is this:

```
Object.prototype <- Array.prototype <- exampleArray instance
```

See snippet:

```js
const exampleArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(exampleArray) === Array.prototype,
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype) === Object.prototype
);
```

The Array *constructor function* - `window.Array` - is not in the prototype chain, so `isPrototypeOf` returns `false`.

The Array constructor function would only have `isPrototypeOf` return `true` if a class extended `Array`, or if it was set to be the internal prototype of a new object via `Object.create`, eg:

```js
class ExtendedArray extends Array {}
console.log(Array.isPrototypeOf(ExtendedArray));

const somethingWeird = Object.create(Array);
console.log(Array.isPrototypeOf(somethingWeird));
```

For completeness, the Array constructor function - being a function - inherits from `Function.prototype`, which inherits from `Object.prototype`:

```js
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Array) === Function.prototype,
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) === Object.prototype
);
```